# Office task pane app: how to do search and replace in a Word document?

Tags: office365

We are developing an Office Task Pane app that search for certain text and replace them by values.

For example, we have a word document like:

```
Total invoice of this year <<thisYear>> is <<totalInvoice>>
```

In task pane app, when user clicks a button, the app should search for text surrounding by <<>>, and replace them with real values from data from Internet. The result should look like:

```
Total invoice of this year 2015 is $2,000,078.34
```

I'm very new to Office Task Pane app, how should I do this?

============== Updated =================

I have done nothing except running the demo from MS. The demo shows how to get selected text from a word document. It is easy to understand.

```
function getDataFromSelection() {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                app.showNotification('The selected text is:', '"' + result.value + '"');
            } else {
                app.showNotification('Error:', result.error.message);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

However, I didn't find any `Find` or `Replace` API, but this:

```
Document API
    Document object
        bindings property
        customXmlParts property
        mode property
        settings property
        url property
        addHandlerAsync method
        getActiveViewAsync method
        getFileAsync method
        getFilePropertiesAsync method
        getSelectedDataAsync method
        goToByIdAsync method
        removeHandlerAsync method
        setSelectedDataAsync method
        ActiveViewChanged event
        SelectionChanged event
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done?

Comment: I updated the question, @DhruvJoshi, please have a look.

Comment: Looking at the business problem statement, I believe you don't need an app for this as Mail Merge in Word document does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp160953.aspx#APIOverview_Context), you can do following

> **Applies to: Content and task pane app types**
>
> To interact with document data in Excel, PowerPoint, and Word, the API provides the Document object. You can use Document object members to access data from the following ways:
>
> 1. Read and write to active selections in the form of text, contiguous
>    cells (matrices), or tables.
> 2. Tabular data (matrices or tables).
> 3. Bindings (created with the "add" methods of the Bindings object).
> 4. Custom XML parts (only for Word).
> 5. Settings or app state persisted per app on the document.

Also a little below it says

> The Document object supports four ways for developers to access
> document contents:
>
> 1. Selection-based access
> 2. Binding-based access
> 3. Custom XML part-based access (Word only)
> 4. Entire document-based access (PowerPoint and Word only)

In [yet another documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj220067.aspx), MS explains that selection is critical part of the apps workflow.
[image: Workflow]

I believe your only routes will be:

1. Ask user to select the whole document and then click on a button to run your replacement code using probably `setSelectedDataAsync` method.
2. Get the complete document using `Document.getFileAsync` method and replace the <<..>> in code and then create a new document. See example for getting the whole content [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj715279.aspx).